# I am trying to delete an item in my list after making changes to it but it won't delete and I dont understand why

Tags: python, list

The aim of my code is to take an input from the user and to check if each character could be a string or an integer. It would then put the character into different lists.

Also if you know a better way to do this please say. This is only thing I could think of.

```
user_inp = input("please give me an input")


def split_func():
    for i in user_inp:
        user_inp_split.append(i)

def check():

    for i in user_inp:
        try :
            temp = int(i)
            items2.append(temp)
            del user_inp_split[i]
            # the line that wont work 


            print (user_inp)

            print (user_inp_split)

        except:
            print ("get to stage 2")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  The code you posted hangs waiting for input (don't insist that we feed your program).  When I give it input, the code exits immediately: you haven't called either of your functions.  You also failed to show your actual and expected output.

Comment: `check` faults on an undefined symbol; your posted code does not produce the problem you partially described.

Comment: BTW: shorter `user_inp_split = list(user_inp)`

Comment: do you get error? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `i` is char from string `user_inp`, not index, so you can't use it as index in `user_inp_split[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, the problem that you have is that you do not have an organized code, i reorganized your code in order to make the task that you want:

```py
user_inp = input("please give me an input: ")
user_inp_split = list(user_inp) #user input converted to list
items2 = [] #Character list
items1 = [] #integer list

def check():
    for i in user_inp_split: #iterates over the user_input list
        try :
            items1.append(int(i,10)) #Convert the items to an integer with base on 10
        except ValueError:
            items2.append(i) #if not, append to the items2 list
    print ("User input {}".format(user_inp))
    print ("Characters {}".format(items2))
    print ("Integers {}".format(items1))
check() #call the function, otherwise it wont work
```

First of all, you must declare the list to be appended to (line 3 and 4), then we must iterate, and check if they are integer, if they can be converted with the built-in function [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), they are integers, otherwise, they are not (lines 8 to 11), finally we print the user input to check that everything is OK.